# Browser not responding for click while Javascript process in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, google-chrome

I'm creating a simple search functionality on a bunch of htmls. I have used simple string utilities in javascript/jQuery to achieve it and it came out good. I create a json string with all the results while processing htmls one by one. On the go I populate the results in a Div by appending the results and it is navigable on click. The problem am facing is the results populated so far are not clickable since the browser not responding until all the results are being processed and entire json is created. After the whole process is finished am able to click and navigate correctly. Any idea why browser hanging/not responding on this javascript process.??

Comment: use a small timeout between loading each page.

Comment: JS runs in a single thread...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript only runs on a single processor thread, meaning it can only actually do 1 thing at a time.  However, javascript can sometimes *act* like it does more than 1 thing at a time by switching between tasks really quickly.  You are experiencing that behavior because you have the thread locked until it completely loads the results.

You didn't post any code, so this is speculation.  I'm guessing that you are looping through the JSON results and appending each iteration.  If you want to still be able to do other things while the results are being appended to the page, you need to wrap the code *inside of your loop* with a `setTimeout()` function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonStr.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //append divs
  }, 25);
}
```

What that code will do is wait 25 milliseconds to append divs each iteration, thus giving your other code time to execute.  You can fine-tune the amount of time between however you like, but that is the gist.

Comment: yep setTimeout has often solved a bunch of undesired behaviours in js for me

Comment: can we able to get the time of running script like. This in console of google chrome  [Violation] 'click' handler took 9656ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 118ms.